# Error Starting R in Ubuntu

Tags: rstudio

The following problem occurred when running R studio.
How can I solve this?

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.12.1+402 "Ocean Storm " (4da58325, 2024-01-29) for Ubuntu Jammy

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio/2023.12.1+402 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 127.

Error output:

```
/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/rsession: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*Log File*

```
[No logs available]
```

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libssl-dev`?

Comment: Can you update your question with details of which Ubuntu version you're using (tag)? You can get this information from the `lsb_release -a` command

Comment: AFAIK libssl.so.3 is provided by the ordinary runtime package libssl3 - it shouldn't need the -dev package. OTOH if you are trying to run this on an earlier Ubuntu release that would have libssl1.1 so you'd be SOL